# Minecraft Mod Issue with Possession

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I have downloaded a few mods: Animals Plus, Mo Creatures, Lycanites Mobs, Furniture, Wallpaper, and Twilight Forest. I tried to research the mods before downloading, but I must of missed something. When I go to the Nether, I get picked up and thrown around to my death. When I click on the button that shows the inventory, it says possession followed by a timer, like a potion would have. Does anyone know if this is a regular Minecraft obstacle or if this is from one of those mods? If anyone knows, do you also know how to defeat it?

Comment: more information would be awesome such as screenshots, version of minecraft, what platform are you playing on etc.

Comment: This is not a regular Minecraft thing, no.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the mod Biomes o' Plenty installed, then you've encountered one of its featured mobs known as [Phantoms](http://biomesoplenty.wikia.com/wiki/Phantom). If you can't see them then you have to enable particles in Minecraft's graphics settings.